# Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoSettings' has no member 'availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes

Tags: swift4, xcode9, coreml

```
@objc func launchCoreML() {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first
    let previewFormat = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType, 
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160, 
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
    ] as [String : Any]

    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

I have an error saying:

> Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoSettings' has no member
>   'availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormat'.

I'm using the beta version of Xcode 9.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In beta 4 this got renamed to `__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormat`. I haven't looked at beta 5 yet.

Comment: Still `__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` in beta 5.

Comment: I am struggling to find same in beta 5 aswell.

Comment: This is happening in Xcode 9 GM as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Using Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) -- cannot solve this issue (

Comment: right answer should be the one from @eharo2. "__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes"

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem after upgrading to Xcode 12.0

It seems that `settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` has been changed to `settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` again in the Final Xcode Release: Version 12.0 (12A7209).   I have been using it without the 'rename' for at least 2 years.   Thx to @Matthijs Hollemans for the help

EDIT:
This is the official response with regards to this change:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86810?answerId=259270022#259270022

This code compiles OK.

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
guard let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first else { return }
let previewFormat = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
    kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
    kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings.init(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            if photoSettings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.count > 0 {
                photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : photoSettings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!]
            }
        }
```